# Get data from Two tables(join) with LINQ and return result into View using MVC 5

Tags: c#, linq, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have two tables: INVENTORY and MINMAX and I want to execute query with join and get the result in the View if reach the minimum qty and maxqty on INVENTORY

In the Controller I have this code:

```html
 public ActionResult DetailsMinMax(string id)
        {
        
  var ListMin = (from i in INVENTORY
                           join m in MINMAX
                           on i.ITEM.Trim() equals m.ITEM.Trim()
                           select new
                           {
                               INVORG = i.INVORG,
                               ITEM = i.ITEM,
                               DESCRIPTION = i.DESCRIPTION,
                               ONHANDQTY = i.ONHANDQTY,
                               MINQTY = m.MINQTY,
                               MAXQTY = m.MAXQTY
                           }).Where(a => a.MINQTY >= a.ONHANDQTY).ToList();

            var ListMAX = (from i in INVENTORY
                           join m in MINMAX
                           on i.ITEM.Trim() equals m.ITEM.Trim()
                           select new
                           {
                               INVORG = i.INVORG,
                               ITEM = i.ITEM,
                               DESCRIPTION = i.DESCRIPTION,
                               ONHANDQTY = i.ONHANDQTY,
                               MINQTY = m.MINQTY,
                               MAXQTY = m.MAXQTY
                           }).Where(a => a.MAXQTY <= a.ONHANDQTY).ToList();
                           
                           return View ();
      
         }
```

**Model**

```html
  public class MINMAX
    {
        public string MINMAXID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string INVORG { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string ITEM { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string DESCRIPTION { get; set; }
        public string PRIMARYUOMCODE { get; set; }
        public decimal MINQTY { get; set; }
        public decimal MAXQTY { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class INVENTORY
    {
    public string INVO { get; set; }
    public string INVORG { get; set; }
    public string ITEM { get; set; }
    public string DESCRIPTION { get; set; }
    public decimal ONHANDQTY{ get; set; }
    }
```

Desired output:

[image]

Comment: hi mj, my code still not working and i need your help to fixed my code and also  i don't have a View to display my desired output.

Comment: You've told us what you want but you haven't told us what the code does **now**. _We can't get you from point A to point B without understanding where point A is._

Comment: doing of this code now is to select  the min and max qty on INVENTORY table, that's it.,thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it's not very clear what your trying to do but as a wild guess I believe that you use the Inventory table to store (item/product) information and the MinMax table is used to store additional information for each existing item like the (min/max quantities of that item). If this is the case I can give you the following suggestion:

You have duplicated data within your tables, try to fix that by changing the schema of the Inventory table to be (Id, Description, CurrentQuantity, InfoId) and the MinMax table to be named as **InventoryInfo** or **InventoryDetail** to have the scheam (Id, ItemId, MinQty, MaxQty). **NOTE**: In this case you will have a One-To-One relationship between **Inventory** and **InventoryInfo** tables which is not quite well treated. The best option for you is to remove the second table (MINMAX) and add the MinQty and MaxQty columns in your Inventory table. Then your query should look like this:

```
var result = InventorySet.Where(x => x.CurrentQty == x.MinQty || x.CurrentQty == x.MaxQty).ToList();
return View(result)
```

PS: I've assumed that this is what you wanted to do. If you haven't solved the problem yet, let me know.